Next Auth session goes away on refreshing the page
I'm using MongoDB as a database and NextAuth for authentication. The problem is that after logging into the account, my session persists if I don't reload the page. I also checked some threads on github, but got no proper solution. I shared my code below, maybe it will help to get an idea of where  the main error is.
[...nextauth].js
import User from "@/models/user";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { connectMongoDB } from "@/lib/mongodb";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password } = credentials;

        try {
          await connectMongoDB();
          const user = await User.findOne({ email });
          if (!user) {
            return null;
          }
          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
          if (!passwordsMatch) {
            return null;
          }
          return { id: user._id.toString(), email: user.email }; // Omitting 'name' field
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error during authorization: ", error);
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
    updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.email = user.email;
      }
      console.log("JWT callback - token:", token);
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = {
        id: token.id,
        email: token.email,
      };
      console.log("Session callback - session:", session);
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/my-account",
  },
});

app.js
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { DefaultSeo } from "next-seo";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Fragment>
        // SEO
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </Fragment>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

dashboard.js
import React from "react";
import { Tabs, TabsContent, TabsList, TabsTrigger } from "@/components/ui/tabs";
import Link from "next/link";
import MyAccountNav from "@/components/MyAccountNav";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";
const dashboard = () => {

     const { data: session } = useSession();
     const router = useRouter();

     useEffect(() => {
       if (!session) {
         // If no session, redirect to the sign-in page
         router.push("/my-account/");
       }
     }, [session, router]);
    return (
        <>
            <MyAccountNav />
        </>
    );
};

export default dashboard;

I've tried many solutions, including wrapping the SessionProvider in app.js, but it didn't work.

I found a solution to fix the issue.
useEffect(() => {
    if (status !== "loading" && !session) {
      router.push("/my-account/");
    }
  }, [status, session, router]);

